# Compare string values and return common values (avoid repetition)

Tags: php, arrays, regex, function, output

I have three strings , and I need to compare each string and the have to return unique values, by excluding the repeated values.

```
$str1 = 1,2,4 ;
$str2 = 2,6 ;
$str3 = 1,4,6 ;
```

Compare this string and return common value and avoid repeated value.

Output as :

```
$output = 1,2,4,6
```

avoid repetition.

Comment: Where is your function?

Comment: what are you comparing ? what needs to be done ?

Comment: i have three inputs likes this str1 , str2 , str3 .. now what i need to do is compare and return value like this. i dont know how to compare in php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation :

Concatenate the three strings and explode them using comma operator in to an array, find the unique entries from that array using `array_unique` and *finally* implode it.

```
echo implode(',',array_unique(explode(',',$str1.','.$str2.','.$str3)));
```

<kbd>[Demonstration - PHP Native Functions](https://eval.in/147491)</kbd>

#### A regex - solution

```
$str = preg_match_all('@[0-9]@',$str1.$str2.$str3,$mtch);
echo implode(',',array_unique($mtch[0]));
```

<kbd>[Demonstration - Regular Expressions](https://eval.in/147494)</kbd>

Comment: Haha nandri maams :) Glad to meet a tamilian :D